# How to remove the word "Figure" from a caption?

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

How to remove a caption when using `figure`. I need to have a figure with no captions or the word `Fig`

`\Figure[!t]()[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}
    {certain caption. }`
[image]

Comment: Don't use `\caption`, then no caption will appear.

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire caption or just the word "Figure" as suggested in the title (which would presumably leave a lone number)? It would help us greatly if you could show us a short example document of your use of `\Figure` instead of a single line of code. I don't think `\Figure` is a standard command and the usage shown in the code does not quite seem to be the same as the `\Figure` command from `easyfig`, so it is not clear what `\Figure` does. The short example document would show us where or how `\Figure` is defined (which package you load for it).

Comment: That all said, usually you would probably use something like `\begin{figure}[t] \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}\end{figure}` to get a floating figure without caption (that is, you simply don't use `\caption` in the normal setup). If you just say `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}` without the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` the image will not float (which might be useful for title pages or other situations where the image position is fixed.) If and how something like this is possible with `\Figure` depends on its definition.

Comment: This is figure command is for ` \documentclass{ieeeaccess}`. I remove caption but I still have the word "Figure" below the map

Comment: Please add the *crucial* information about your document class directly to your question. It is too easy to overlook that in the comments. Please let me re-iterate my request for a full example document, that makes it much easier for people to help you. It would also help greatly if you could add a link to the place where we can obtain `ieeeaccess.cls`.

Comment: As far as I can see (from a random version of `ieeeaccess.cls` I found on google), the `\Figure` command always brings its own `\caption`. If you really don't want that caption, the only proper way to solve this that I can see is not to use `\Figure`, but instead `\begin{figure}[t] \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}\end{figure}` or `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}` as already suggested. I don't know what the IEEE (editors) will have to say about not using `\Figure` or about not adding captions to figures, but that is between you and them.

Comment: I know but this is a work around to add a table made with tikz to this ieee format

Comment: I used the command `\begin{figure}[!t] \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figures/loc.pdf}\end{figure}` but the figure override the existing writing. it does not appear  like a normal figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally redefine `\caption` to ignore its argument.

```latex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{}%
\Figure[!t]()[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}{}
\endgroup

\EOD

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in preamble

```
%set empty label
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

[image]

in env

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{vipers-fradi.jpg}
% set caption here
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple,name=MyFig,labelfont=bf,textfont=it}
\caption{"Vipers Kristiansand - Ferencvaros"}
\end{figure}
```

[image]